# Bound content in Popover is not shown

Tags: sapui5

I created a popover which is called on mouseover via `addEventDelegate`.
The popover has a text element with binding to my Model.

The fragment:

```xml
<Popover xmlns="sap.m"
    id="myCardPopover"
    showHeader="false"
    contentWidth="260px"
    placement="Bottom">
    <Text id="myCardPopoverText" text="{propertyModel>Tooltip}" />
</Popover>
```

Register the browser events:

```js
attachCardPopoverOnMouseover: function () {
    var rootHBox = this.byId("myReportCardContent");
    rootHBox.addEventDelegate({
        onmouseover: function () {
            this.timeId = setTimeout(() => that.onOpenCardPopover(this), 600);
        },
        onmouseout: function () {
            clearTimeout(this.timeId) || that.onCloseCardPopover(this);
        }
    }, rootHBox);
},
```

The event listener:

```js
onOpenCardPopover: function (oControl) {
    this.oCardTooltipPopover.then(function (oPopover) {
        var oContext = oControl.getBindingContext("propertyModel");
        oPopover.setBindingContext(oContext);
        oPopover.openBy(oControl);
    });
},
```

The `Popover` itself is a dependent of multiple controls created from an aggregation binding and is created in `onAfterRendering`.

```js
// Fragment required from "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
createCardPopover: function () {
    var oView = this.getView();
    var oRootHBox = this.byId("myReportCardContent");
    if (!this.oCardTooltipPopover) {
        this.oCardTooltipPopover = Fragment.load({
            id: oView.getId(),
            name: "namespace.view.CardPopup"
        }).then(function (oPopover) {
            oRootHBox.addDependent(oPopover);
            return oPopover;
        });
    }
},
```

When I hover over one of my controls, I only get an empty popover. The bound text isn't shown.

However, when I lookup the created popover in the UI5 debug tools, the binding seems correct and also the text is shown up there.
The text's `<span>` element in the DOM is also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] multiple controls created from an aggregation binding

With `this.byId("myReportCardContent")`, you're accessing the template control rather than the actual rendered ones. A `template` in aggregation binding is usually a static control (i.e. without propagated models and contexts) that the ManagedObject will [`clone`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject#methods/clone) for each data object. **After cloning,** the parent models and contexts are propagated to *those clones*, and not to the internal template control.

So if you add the popover to the `dependent` aggregation of the *template* (`oRootHBox`), there is no context to propagate. The binding paths in the fragment definition stay unresolved.

---

How the issue can be circumvented is up to you. There are many approaches to show something on mouseover. Just avoid manipulating the template after rendering.

Comment: This was the neccessary information I needed. I always tried to get the template from my Event which is of course undefined. Instead I get the right item via ```getDependents()``` of my ```oEvent.getSource()```. Thank you!