# How to get binding context of the second model?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

My Fiori application has a view for which two models are set. The first model is set by default in `manifest.json` (OData), the second model I set in the controller.

The data of the second model are displayed in `sap.m.TextArea`. If I try to get its binding context, the output is `undefined`.

This is how I set second model:

```js
onInit: function() {
  var oLocalModel = {
    Text: "test"
  };
  // JSONModel required from "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
  var oModel = new JSONModel(oLocalModel);
  this.getView().setModel(oModel, "localData");
},
```

This is how I try to get the binding context of the TextArea:

```js
onSendMail: function(oEvent) {
 var oLocalContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("localData"); // undefined
 var oLocalContext = this.byId("zgutMailFormText").getBindingContext("localData"); // undefined too 
},
```

```xml
<TextArea id="zgutMailFormText" value="{localData>/Text}">
  <layoutData>
    <l:GridData span="XL2 L3 M3 S8" />
  </layoutData>
</TextArea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the context depends on your application code which I don't see much in your question. But since the `localData` model is a client-side model, and since the binding path is already known (absolute path), you could simply create the context with the [method `createBindingContext`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Model#methods/createBindingContext).

```js
onSendMail: function(oEvent) {
  const oLocalContext = this.getView().getModel("localData").createBindingContext("/");
  // ...
},
```

There could be many reasons why a control returns no context:

- The control has simply no context. Contexts are created by the framework automatically for **resolving relative binding paths.** Since your `TextArea` binds data with an absolute path (`localData>/Text`), no context needs to be created. The path can be resolved immediately.
- The control you accessed (e.g. `this.byId("zgutMailFormText")`) is part of a template control. Templates don't contain any contexts. Only the rendered clones do.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68379873/5846045) for more explanation.
- Parent controls themselves have no contexts bound, so there is no context to propagate.

From the [API reference: `sap/ui/model/Context`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Context):

> The `Context` is a pointer to an object in the model data. A relative binding needs a context as a reference point in order to resolve its path; without a context, a relative binding is unresolved and does not point to model data. Context instances can, for example, be created in the following ways:
>
> - by a `sap.ui.model.ListBinding` for each list entry,
> - as the single context associated with a `sap.ui.model.ContextBinding`,
> - by calling [`sap.ui.model.Model#createBindingContext`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.Model#methods/createBindingContext).