# SAPUI5 ComboBox getBinding() returning undefined

Tags: sapui5

I have a ComboBox1 outside a Table and a ComboBox2 inside the Table, ComboBox1 (outside the Table) I can access the comboBox .getBinding("items") but ComboBox2 (inside the Table) I cannot.

I need to filter ComboBox2 (within the Table) dynamically based on the bind of another column, the trigger occurs when the onValueChange method is changed.

I'm using the same data binding in both combos.

Can you help me?

XML

```
<ComboBox
    id="cmbBox1"
    selectedKey="{naoConformidade}"
    items="{/ncCollection}"
    showSecondaryValues="true"
    selectionChange="onNcSelected">
    <core:ListItem key="{code}" text="{name}" additionalText="{key}" />
  </ComboBox>
  <IconTabBar
    expanded="{device>/isNoPhone}"
    class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
    <items>
      <IconTabFilter
        key="info"
        text="Conteúdo">
        <Table id="idProductsTable"
          inset="false"
          items="{/detail/lines}">
          <columns>
            <Column>
              <Text text="Especificação" />
            </Column>
            <Column>
              <Text text="Valor Encontrado" />
            </Column>
            <Column>
              <Text text="NC" />
            </Column>
          </columns>
          <items>
            <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
              <cells>
                <Text text="{nomeEspecificacao}" />
                <Input value="{vlrEncontrado}" change="onValueChange" />
                <ComboBox
                  id="cmbBox2"
                  selectedKey="{naoConformidade}"
                  items="{/ncCollection}"
                  showSecondaryValues="true"
                  selectionChange="onNcSelected">
                  <core:ListItem key="{code}" text="{name}" additionalText="{key}" />
                </ComboBox>
              </cells>
            </ColumnListItem>
          </items>
        </Table>
```

Controller

```
onValueChange: function (oEvent) {
       this.byId("cmbBox1").getBinding('items') //return bind OK
       this.byId("cmbBox2").getBinding('items') //return undefined
    }
```

I must be doing something stupid wrong.

I created a code example to demonstrate the problem, I believe I am making a mistake in data binding. Here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/andersonline2013/9wtd4qjh/13/

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd ComboBox (`cmbBox2`) is part of the template control for the Table's `items` aggregation binding. The template control itself is not rendered but cloned. Only the cloned ones will return `thatClonedComboBox.getBinding("items")`.

See my answers to similar questions:

- [How to get binding context of the second model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69501979/how-to-get-binding-context-of-the-second-model/69506738#69506738)
- [Bound content in Popover is not shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366143/bound-content-in-popover-is-not-shown/68379873#68379873)

Comment: Boghyon Hoffmann's thanks for the help. I understand the problem, but is there any way to resolve this? My intention is to apply a dynamic filter to cmbBox2.

Comment: Although not my favourite approach.. the oEvent.getSource() will give you the Input being edited. With a couple of .getParent() you'll reach the Row control and from that you can get the cell that has your ComboBox and then the control that you need. You'll have to be careful everytime you change the table struture though.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works for me, the difference is that I created a local model for binding the items to the Comboboxes. I believe you should review your connections.
Here's the simplified way I used to test:

```xml
<ComboBox
    id="cmbBox1"
    selectedKey="{naoConformidade}"
    items="{/ncCollection}"
    showSecondaryValues="true"
    selectionChange="onNcSelected">
    <core:ListItem
        text="{code}"
        additionalText="{key}" />
</ComboBox>
<Table id="idProductsTable">
    <columns>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Especificação" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="Valor Encontrado" />
        </Column>
        <Column>
            <Text text="NC" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
            <cells>
                <Text text="nomeEspecificacao" />
                <Input
                    value="vlrEncontrado"
                    change="onValueChange" />
                <ComboBox
                    id="cmbBox2"
                    selectedKey="{naoConformidade}"
                    items="{/ncCollection}"
                    showSecondaryValues="true"
                    selectionChange="onNcSelected">
                    <core:ListItem
                        text="{code}"
                        additionalText="{key}" />
                </ComboBox>
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

Controller:

```js
onInit: function () {
    const oModel = new JSONModel({
        ncCollection: [
            {
                code: 'asd123',
                key: 'key123'
            },
            {
                code: 'dfhgs345345',
                key: 'key321'
            },
            {
                code: 'gjfg46457',
                key: 'key231'
            }
        ]
    });

    this.getView().setModel(oModel);
},
onValueChange: function () {
    console.log(`List items of cmbBox1: `, this.byId("cmbBox1").getBinding('items'));
    console.log(`List items of cmbBox2: `, this.byId("cmbBox2").getBinding('items'));
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. I created a code example to demonstrate the problem, I believe I am making a mistake in data binding. Here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/andersonline2013/9wtd4qjh/13/

Comment: Doglas, I saw that your profile is from Portugal, I'm from Brazil, add me on LinkedIn so we can exchange experiences. https://www.linkedin.com/in/anderson-souza-7a199186/

Comment: If the `Table` has no aggregation binding, the inner `ComboBox` is rendered together with the single `ColumnListItem`, hence working here. But if the Table has aggregation binding, the `ColumnListItem` in the XML is evaluated as a _template_ control: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77889373/5846045